# PrimeFaces.current().dialog().openDynamic(...) doesn't work using '<p:poll ...'

Tags: primefaces, dialog, frameworks

Given this code in the named bean `TestView` I'd like to open a dynamic dialog :

```java
    public void dynamicMenue(String menue) {
        System.out.println("dynamicMenue: " + menue);
        PrimeFaces.current().dialog().openDynamic("menue");
    };
```

Using

```xml
    <p:commandButton value="onSubmit" action="#{testView.dynamicMenue('submit')}" />
```

this works, but using

```xml
    <p:poll interval="10" listener="#{testView.dynamicMenue('autoUpdate')}" />
```

it doesn't.

What am I missing?

I've put a minimal project on https://github.com/mafulafunk/primefaces-test
to illustrate this behaviour.

Comment: I am looking at this and you are right its really interesting. The code almost is identical but the poller is definitely not sending back the `<eval>` to open the dialog.

Answer (score 1):

I know why.  It is because the Dialog handling is done in the PrimeFaces `OutcomeRenderer` which `p:poll` does NOT extend or use when constructing its AJAX requests.  Only Buttons and Links are allowed to open the Dialog Framework.

There is an easy workaround though.

1. Set your button to invisible with `display:none` and give it a widget var...

```xml
<p:commandButton 
value="onSubmit" 
action="#{testView.dynamicMenue('submit')} 
style="display:none" 
widgetVar="wgtOpenDialog" />
```

2. Change your p:poller to click the button.

```xml
 <p:poll 
interval="10" 
onstart="PF('wgtOpenDialog').click(); return false;" />
```

Comment: You can probably use RemoteCommand as well.

Comment: I thought RemoteCommand might have the same issue a Poller as its not using OutComeTargetRenderer?